# Override a single method in a Cakephp Core Class?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to override cakephp's cakeEmail class's send method.  I was working off of
[CakePhp: Cake Email AfterSend event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138083/cakephp-cake-email-aftersend-event)

I can overwrite the entire class by using the cake cookbook method: "To override the Dispatcher class, create app/Lib/Routing/Dispatcher.php"

How do I overwrite a single method instead?  Is this the most maintainable way to approach this?  Thank you.

Cakephp 2.8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I overwrite a single method instead? Is this the most maintainable way to approach this? Thank you.

Standard OOP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Extend the class, overload method you want, use that class.

Comment: Thank you I got it working! I am now trying to follow your instructions for Globally changing the class. I have tried variations of your method but have been unable to cause the class to redirect any input would be invaluable.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326066/cakephp-globally-override-class)