# CakePHP Globally override class?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I reconfigured my cakeEmail class to log to a specific type by rewriting the send method.  I would like to use this override globally. My current single file setup uses /Lib/CustomCakeEmail.php with

```
App:uses('CustomCakeEmail', 'Lib');
```

[CakePhp: Cake Email AfterSend event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138083/cakephp-cake-email-aftersend-event) suggests a method to globally override using AppController but I have been unable to even trigger the debugger in

```
App::uses('CustomCakeEmail', 'Lib');
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function getEmailInstance($config = null) {
        CakeLog::write('debug', 'appcontroller triggered');
        return new CustomCakeEmail($config);
    }
```

What is the correct way to implement this global override?

CakePHP Version 2.8.4

Comment: You can't have both, an extended class and exchanging the core class for it (ie overriding it globally). Either "globally" use the `getEmailInstance()` method to retrieve the an email class instance, or reimplement the whole email class and override the core one, you have to pick one, and I'd suggest to chose the former. On a related note, why don't you just configure the `log` option accordingly?

Comment: I am logging any sent emails to a database through a custom logging engine, cakeEmail logs Email as type 'debug' without a config option available, I am seeking to prevent them from being logged redundantly in debug.log by changing the send method to log on a custom type.  Bottom line I am seeking to do this in the most maintainable way.  I have overwritten the entire class in the standard cakephp way but was looking for a better option.  Could you elaborate on the email class instance approach please?

Comment: "_... without a config option available_" That's not correct, as mentioned, it uses the `log` config option, which you can use to define the type/level as well as the scope. **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8.4/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L1174-L1190**. I don't know what you want me to elaborate on with regards to the instance approach? You need to be a little more specific as to what exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: Thank you for getting me to take a second look at the config! I had not understood the config options and do not need to override anything now.  Talk about heart surgery for a splinter.

Comment: Side question about stack exchange culture.  How can I give you credit for fixing my this question?  Or, did you use comments because you don't care?

Comment: I just started with comments because I was unsure what exactly your problem with the shown code was. Usually I'd post a solution as an actual answer that can be accepted, thus marking the question as solved, but I'm note sure whether the answer would be of much help for future readers in this case.